# I want to remove .php from http://example.com/blog/product.php using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have tried lots to remove the .php from URL using htaccess. I tried many script but not get the proper result.

RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]

I tried above code to remove .php but not working for me.

Comment: This question must have been answered at least hundred times. Use the "search" option.

Comment: Not solved... please comment code of it..

Comment: The code is in the answers of the duplicate question. Copy-pasting the code here just so you don't have to click on the link won't be helpful for anyone.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]

Comment: Not working...I want http://example.com/blog/product radher than http://example.com/blog/product.php

Comment: Ok thank you.. It's working for my other page..

Comment: so... it's ok or not?
need more help?

Comment: RewriteRule ^blog/(.+) /$1.php [L]

Comment: Thanks for the help...

Comment: Sure ... please mark my post as usefull , thanks :)